# Little confused about multi-threading concepts

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a few questions about Java multi-threading. I am currently learning different methods of multi-threading. My first question is, what happens to the thread after the code in it is done running? Do I need to Stop/Kill the thread? I am currently making a class for each thread and implementing Runnable in each class. I then start the thread in the main class using `new ThreadClass();.` In the constructor of the Thread class, I have it set to make a Thread named "second." If I add `new ThreadClass()` twice in the main method, are both threads named "second"? Thanks.

Comment: Multi-threading is the topic which confuses the most people I suspect. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first question is, what happens to the thread after the code in it is done running? Do I need to Stop/Kill the thread?

The thread stops when it has nothing to do.  If you have an ExecutorService, you have to use shutdown when you have finished with it.

> If I add new ThreadClass() twice in the main method, are both threads named "second"?

You are making the code the same. This doesn't mean the name of the thread has to be the same (and vice-versa)

Comment: @MiserableVariable Thank you for the correction. It looked wrong but the words were spelt correctly. :(

Comment: Well wouldnt the name be the same automatically? My ThreadClass construcotr looks like this: `public class ThreadClass implements Runnable{
           Thread second;
           
   public ThreadClass() {
      second = new Thread(this, "Second Thread");
      second.start(); 
   }`

Comment: Only if you "automatically" give it the same name.  In this case you would have two threads with the same name running different objects. I suggest giving different threads, different names so you know which is which in stack traces and debugging.

Comment: How would I change the name if Im using only one thread class? The thread class constructor runs second.start and it creates a thread named second.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) rather than `ThreadClass`.

When the `run` method of a thread returns then the thread will stop.  If you only specify the name in the second thread then only that thread will have the name "second".  The first thread is unaffected.

You should avoid calling [stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) if at all possible as it does not allow the thread to exit cleanly.

Comment: No I meant ThreadClass. That is the name of the class that creates the new thread. Look at the comment I put on the previous answer.